# Install Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 12.4

Tags: 12.04, installation, python

I have install Ubuntu several day ago.

I have install Python on Windows before and everything was simple. Now on Ubuntu I’m getting stuck with installation of Python. So my question is:

> How can I install Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 12.4?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python 2.7 is included in 12.04 by default. 
If for some reason it is not, run `sudo apt-get install python2.7`

To check if you ave python and what version run `python --version`

To install IDLE: `sudo apt-get install idle`

Comment: But how can I install IDLE??